# Efficient way to expand a DataFrame in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe with exposure episodes per case:

```
using DataFrames
using Dates
df = DataFrame(id = [1,1,2,3], startdate = [Date(2018,3,1),Date(2019,4,2),Date(2018,6,4),Date(2018,5,1)], enddate = [Date(2019,4,4),Date(2019,8,5),Date(2019,3,1),Date(2019,4,15)])
```

I want to expand each episode to its constituent days, eliminating any duplicate days per case resulting from overlapping episodes (case 1 in the example dataframe):

```
    s = similar(df, 0)
    for row in eachrow(df)
        tf = DataFrame(row)
        ttf = repeat(tf, Dates.value.(row.enddate - row.startdate) + 1)
        ttf.daydate = ttf.startdate .+ Dates.Day.(0:nrow(ttf) - 1) #a record for each day between start and end days (inclusive)
        ttf.start = ttf.daydate .== ttf.startdate                  #a flag to indicate this record was at the start of an episode
        ttf.end = ttf.daydate .== ttf.enddate                      #a flag to indicate this record was at the end of an episode
        append!(s, ttf, cols=:union)
    end
    sort!(s, [:id,:daydate,:startdate, order(:enddate, rev=true)])
    unique!(s,[:id,:daydate]) #to eliminate duplicate dates in the case of episode overlaps (e.g. case 1)
```

I have a strong suspicion that there is a more efficient way of doing this than the brute force method I came up with and any help will be appreciated.

Implementation note: In the actual implementation there are several hundred thousand cases, each with relatively few episodes (median = 1, 75 percentile 3, maximum 20), but spanning 20 years or more of exposure resulting in a very large dataset (several 100 million records). To fit into available memory I have partitioned the dataset on id and used the Threads.@threads macro to loop through the partitions in parallel. The primary purpose of this decomposition into days is not just to eliminate overlaps, but to join the data with other exposure data that is available on a per day basis.

Comment: Your specification is incomplete. In order to help you I would need to know for the case of two or more episodes overlapping: 1) which episode `startdate` and `enddatae` you want to keep? 2) for which episodes you want to keep in `start` and `end` the value `true` (as now you keep just one row so it is kind of random what is left in these columns and depends on the order how episodes appear in the original data frame).

Comment: Apologies, I left out a sorting step before the `unique!(....` step.    `sort!(s, [:id,:DayDate,:startdate, order(:enddate, rev=true)])`. So the date selected is the one from the episode that started first, or ended last if there is a tie. The start and end flags can be dropped, really only there to indicate a gap in day dates where consecutive expanded episodes not abut on each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that should be efficient:

```
dfs = sort(df, [:startdate, order(:enddate, rev=true)])
gdf = groupby(dfs, :id, sort=true)

function process(startdate, enddate)
    start = startdate[1]
    stop = enddate[1]
    res_daydate = collect(start:Day(1):stop)
    res_startdate = fill(start, length(res_daydate))
    res_enddate = fill(stop, length(res_daydate))

    for i in 2:length(startdate)
        if startdate[i] > res_daydate[end]
            start = startdate[i]
            stop = enddate[i]
        elseif enddate[i] > res_daydate[end]
            start = res_daydate[end] + Day(1)
            stop = enddate[i]
        end
        new_daydate = start:Day(1):stop
        append!(res_daydate, new_daydate)
        append!(res_startdate, fill(startdate[i], length(new_daydate)))
        append!(res_enddate, fill(stop, length(new_daydate)))
    end

    return (startdate=res_startdate, enddate=res_enddate, daydate=res_daydate)
end

combine(gdf, [:startdate, :enddate] => process => AsTable)
```

(but please check it with larger data against your implementation if it is correct as I have just written it quickly to show you how to do performant implementations with DataFrames.jl)

Comment: I used two data sets (A: 127K episodes => 160M days and B: 280K episodes => 800M days). A took 47s vs 81s for the original brute force algorithm. B took 4m23s vs 4m24s. The actual implementation showed a bigger difference, 52 vs 195s for A & 320s vs 1446s for B. There was a big difference in memory allocations: 973M allocations totaling 52GB vs 5G allocations totaling 108G for A and 5G allocations totaling 268GB vs 26G allocations totaling 521GB. I used an AMD Ryzen 3800X with 64GB RAM running Win10. The speed with which julia processes huge datasets is amazing. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a more complete solution that takes into account some essential details. Each episode is associated with additional attributes, as an example I used locationid (place where the exposure took place) and the need to indicate whether there was a gap between subsequent episodes. The original solution also did not cater for the special case where an episode is fully contained within another episode - such episodes should not be expanded.

```
using Dates
using DataFrames

function process(startdate, enddate, locationid)
    start = startdate[1]
    stop = enddate[1]
    location = locationid[1]
   res_daydate = collect(start:Day(1):stop)
    res_startdate = fill(start, length(res_daydate))
    res_enddate = fill(stop, length(res_daydate))
    res_location = fill(location, length(res_daydate))
    gap = 0
    res_gap = fill(0, length(res_daydate))
    for i in 2:length(startdate)
        if startdate[i] > res_daydate[end]
            start = startdate[i]
        elseif enddate[i] > res_daydate[end]
            start = res_daydate[end] + Day(1)
        else
            continue #this episode is contained within the previous episode
        end
        if  start - res_daydate[end] > Day(1)
            gap = gap==0 ? 1 : 0
        end 
        stop = enddate[i]
        location = locationid[i]
        new_daydate = start:Day(1):stop
        append!(res_daydate, new_daydate)
        append!(res_startdate, fill(startdate[i], length(new_daydate)))
        append!(res_enddate, fill(stop, length(new_daydate)))
        append!(res_location, fill(location, length(new_daydate)))
        append!(res_gap, fill(gap, length(new_daydate)))
    end

    return (daydate=res_daydate, startdate=res_startdate, enddate=res_enddate, locationid=res_location, gap = res_gap)
end

function eliminateoverlap()
    df = DataFrame(id = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4], startdate = [Date(2018,3,1),Date(2019,4,2),Date(2018,6,4),Date(2018,5,1), Date(2019,5,1), Date(2012,1,1), Date(2012,2,2)], 
                   enddate = [Date(2019,4,4),Date(2019,8,5),Date(2019,3,1),Date(2019,4,15),Date(2019,6,15),Date(2012,6,30), Date(2012,2,10)], locationid=[10,11,21,30,30,40,41])
    dfs = sort(df, [:startdate, order(:enddate, rev=true)])
    gdf = groupby(dfs, :id, sort=true)
    r = combine(gdf, [:startdate, :enddate, :locationid] => process => AsTable)
    df = combine(groupby(r, [:id,:gap,:locationid]), :daydate => minimum => :StartDate, :daydate => maximum => :EndDate)
    return df
end

df = eliminateoverlap()
```